# Switch site from one server to another without changing DNS

Tags: linux, web-hosting, apache-2.4

I have two identical servers, one with IP address 1.1.1.1 and one with IP address 2.2.2.2.

They both run Ubuntu with Apache 2.4.

I have a domain name. It's A record is set to 1.1.1.1.

I want to be able to quickly change this so that without modifying the DNS, the site is served from 2.2.2.2.

Effectively I want server 1.1.1.1 to be able to say "pass through me, I'll proxy 2.2.2.2 to you seamlessly".

Is this possible/straightforward?

This would be a temporary measure. We can assume that 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 are permanently on, and have a good network connection between them.

Comment: This is called a reverse proxy. There are several modules for apache which provide this functionality. You might for instance wish to look at mod_proxy http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: The ideal approach might be based on the reason *why* you want to switch from one to the other, and how often that might happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely tell Apache to reverse-proxy requests to another host.

Enable the relevant Apache modules. On Debian and Ubuntu, that's something like:

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Then configure the reverse-proxy in the Apache config on 1.1.1.1. On Debian and Ubuntu, you'll probably want to use a "site" in `/etc/sites-available`.

Something like this should work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://2.2.2.2/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The full [documentation for mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) has more details.